# Grails "deep" criteria + one-to-many relation

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following table structures:

```
Task - (has one) - mandate
Mandate - (has many) - mandateContacts (of type Contact)
Contact
```

Of course, Hibernate created a table called `mandate_contact` which links those contacts to a mandate.

I have to write a criteria starting from the `Task` table which should sound like:

`Fetch a task if one of the contacts associated to a mandate has a specific name.`

So far, I have created aliases like:

```
createAlias('mandate', 'mnd', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple using the [criteria builder](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html):

```
def results = Task.createCiteria().list() {
  mandate {
    mandateContacts {
      eq('name', 'whatever value you want to match')
    }
  }
}
```

The above assumes that your `Task` domain class which has a `mandate` property of the `Mandate` domain class type. The `Mandate` has a collection called `mandateContacts` which is a collection of the `Contact` domain class and that the `Contact` domain class has a property called `name` which you want to match against.

I recommend you read the documentation I linked to to understand createCriteria and how it functions.

Comment: and what if in the `mandateContacts` table I only have a contact id which points to an entry in the contact table?